# Troubleshooting a Java program that causes a server to hang with "too many files open"

Tags: java, linux

I have a Java program runs (on linux) for a while and then causes the server to lock up with "Too many files open"

After restarting the machine, I run the java program again and then execute the lsof command against it's pid. A large number of lines with the following output are produced:

```
java    971 uknown  980u     sock                0,9       0t0  20461 protocol: TCPv6
```

Does this means the program is opening multiple tcp connections & not closing them?

What further steps can i take to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your program is opening file descriptors but not closing them. It may be sockets or file handlers. So it is causing resource leak. Make sure all file handlers are closed and make it ready for garbage collected.

As dan1st pointed out in comment, one preventive measure to avoid this scenario is using try-with-resources. This will implements the AutoClosable interface and make sure automatic resource closing.

Comment: Just a note/hint for the OP and possible future readers: use `try-with-resource`s as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to narrow it down a bit - given the output of lsof states "sock", "protocol: TCPv6" does this not mean it's definitely sockets and not files? Or would the same result for open files that happen to be network mounts?

Comment: @auser Can you please share the exact command you used with its options

Comment: lsof -p 971   # 971 is the PID of the java program

Comment: My best bet, it is a socket .  I am assuming 20461 is a port number and it captures protocol as TCPv6

Comment: Root cause of the issue in case anyone is interested - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25348

Comment: @auser   Did you get a solution for this? I am facing same issue, but I am unable to figure out where the resources are getting leaked.